# Detect media play / pause events

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, events, mediaplayer

I want to pause playback after headphones have been unplugged, then resume after they were plugged back in.

My current solution uses ACPI to detect plug / unplug, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected/642404#642404). To play / pause the playback, I use `xdotool key XF86AudioPlay`.

**This solution works fine in the basic case:**

- music is playing, headphones are plugged in
- headphones are unplugged **=>** music pauses
- headphones are plugged back in **=>** music continues playing.

However, I don't want to resume playback if it wasn't **active** when the headphones were unplugged.

**Imagine this scenario:**

- start up the PC with headphones in,
- play music,
- pause music,
- unplug headphones,
- plug headphones back in.

The last point is where the problem lies – the playback would resume after the headphones are plugged back in, although it was not active at the time they were unplugged.

Moreover, on my system, `xdotool key XF86AudioPlay` simply toggles the playback, whereas `xdotool key XF86AudioPause` does nothing. That makes things even worse:

- start PC with headphones in,
- play music,
- pause music,
- unplug headphones *(MUSIC STARTS PLAYING!)*.

---

So what I need is to **detect play / pause / stop events** as well as plug / unplug events, to be able to correctly react in all possible scenarios.

This state machine describes the desired operation:
[image: Unplug-pause FSM]

---

The one idea that came to my mind is to re-bind the keyboard shortcuts for play / pause / stop to add the state machine logic. This has the drawback that playback *always* has to be controlled using these keyboard shortcuts, instead of eg. Rhythmbox buttons, which is somewhat impractical.

Also, if I close Rhythmbox while playing, the state machine will stay in a `playing` state. Of course I could have a 'daemon' which will wait until Rhythmbox is closed, and then set the state to `stopped`. But what if it's not Rhythmbox that plays the music, what if it's for example VLC, etc.? This approach is ugly and unreliable, so I would like to avoid it.

---

**My question:** How to detect when media playback was paused / resumed / stopped?

Comment: If you are using Rythmbox (exclusively), you'll have to modify the source to make its internal state (playing/pausing/stopped) available to you, for example by writing the state to a file when it changes. You'll have to do the same for every other mediaplayer you use.

Comment: @dirkt I have thought about that. Apart from Rhythmbox I only use VLC, with which it shouldn't be difficult to do detect if it's running / playing / etc. With Rhythmbox it's a little tricky. It would be fairly easy, using `rhythmbox-client` with parameters `--check-running` and `--print-playing`, if the latter didn't print the name of the song also when it's paused. Still, a relatively clean solution would be to add another option, eg. `--is-paused` or so. But then both `rhythmbox` and `rhythmbox-client` source would have to be modified. Also, I would prefer this to be portable across players.

Comment: The easiest thing is really to modify the source(s). There is no generally accepted API to indicate what a media player is doing. Another thing you can do is to check the state of the Pulseaudio streams (e.g. with `pacmd list-sink-inputs`, look at `state`), but that requires the media player to pause the stream if it is paused (which some media players may do, and some may not, and I can't check for Rythmbox because I don't have it installed).

Comment: Regarding modifying the sources: if I only wanted to support Rhythmbox, I could enable debug output from which I would know when the state changes to playing / paused / etc. But since Rhythmbox changes the sink state to `CORKED` after it's been paused, I will probably use the Pulseaudio approach – thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to check the state of the Pulseaudio streams, e.g. with `pacmd list-sink-inputs` (look at `state`), or interacting directly with the Pulseaudio demon in a programming language of your choice.

That requires the media player to pause the stream (change `state` from `RUNNING` to `CORKED`) if the player itself is paused. Some media players may do that, and some may not.

Comment: You can also add that `pactl subscribe` can be used to listen for Pulseaudio events (eg. `Event 'change' on sink-input #1`). Then you use `pacmd list-sink-inputs` to find out whether the playback has been paused/stopped or started/resumed.